# How do I use RSpec to test that a class method called at class definition time gets executed?

Tags: ruby, rspec, class-method

How do I write a test to ensure that `::base_uri` is part of the class definition, for `MyClass`? Sample code follows.

```
require 'httparty'

class MyClass
  include HTTParty

  base_uri 'https://www.google.com'
end

describe MyClass do
  it "should call base_uri" do
    MyClass.should_receive(:base_uri)
    MyClass.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i recommend you when in doubt take a look on how your gem implements/tests the code youre calling. So this is how HTTParty's [#base_uri](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/spec/httparty_spec.rb#L84) code is tested.
And then you can write.

```
  it 'should have this base uri' do
     MyClass.base_uri.should == 'my_base_uri'
  end
```

I don't think that testing that the #base_uri is called on your class will give you the warranty that it will work as expected. I prefer to test if the value is really filled, instead of the method call.

Comment: Thank you, this works, and I will keep your idea in mind. Very helpful.